# Cut string on many parts

Tags: ruby

How can I cut string on many parts. I have string like:

```
@abc = 'http://somesite.com/abcdrer/media/picture/abc.jpb'
```

and I know that i can do:

```
@str = @abc.index('/media')
```

so this will return index where "/media" starts (right?) . Now I must delete index from 0 to index returned by @str. How can I delete chosen index from string?

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be? `"/media/picture/abc.jpb"`?

Comment: i want to delete everything that is before "/media"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@abc = 'http://somesite.com/abcdrer/media/picture/abc.jpb'
@abc.slice(@abc.index("/media"), @abc.length)
#=> "/media/picture/abc.jpb"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex:

```
@str = @abc[%r{/media.+}]
 => "/media/picture/abc.jpb"
```

Comment: Use `%r` to create your regular expression instead of bare `/`. That will help you avoid "leaning-toothpick syndrome": `%r{/media.+}`.

Comment: Duly appreciated and incorporated.

Answer (score 1):

Regex will do a better job here. It takes from /media to the end (0 to index is "deleted")

```
@str = @abc[/\/media.*$/]
```

Comment: Use %r to create your regular expression instead of bare /. That will help you avoid "leaning-toothpick syndrome": `%r{/media.*$}`. And, as @sawa says, `$` is redundant, making this: `%r{/media.*}`.

Answer (score -1):

Split the String and get the last element of the Array:

```
@str = @abc.split("/media").last
```

Comment: The OP wants from "/media" on to the end. This returns "/picture/abc.jpb".